# How to model switching losses in transistors in Simulink

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, simulation, igbt, simulink

I'm trying to model the switching losses of an IGBT in Simulink. I've researched however I can't find any literature on how to actually just model the switching losses?

I was potentially thinking about trying to extract the current and voltage through an IGBT and then use that to calculate the lost power however that wouldn't work as I wouldn't know the current and voltage at the period of switching.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can model these switching losses or maybe recommended readings?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Simulink or simscape. Variable step or fixed?

Comment: Hi, I'm modelling an entire wind turbine so some aspects of the turbine model are simulink however the IGBT's are part of simscape. I'm not sure about the step however -  I haven't really played around with any parameters for this so I'd assume fixed. Thanks

Comment: Have solved this. I just chose an IGBT that was valid for my required parameters and used the formula on page 5 of this document (https://www.dynexsemi.com/Portals/0/assets/downloads/DNX_AN6156.pdf)